# What does this ASM code snippet mean?

Tags: x86, boot, linker-scripts

I've been trying to learn about Linux boot-up process from this (https://github.com/0xAX/linux-insides/blob/master/Booting/linux-bootstrap-1.md) tutorial, and very early on I encountered the following code snippet.

```
SECTIONS {
    _ROMTOP = 0xfffffff0;
    . = _ROMTOP;
    .reset . : {
        *(.reset)
        . = 15 ;
        BYTE(0x00);
    }
}
```

I haven't dealt with much of ASM before, but I've never seen anything like that. What does it do? What do curly bracers mean?

Comment: That is not assembly, that's part of a linker script. That tutorial really shouldn't have showed that, it's not truly relevant, just confusing.

Comment: Thank you! It actually did confuse the heck out of me. I guess I'll just skip that part.

Answer (score 2):

That is not assembly, that's part of a linker script. That tutorial really shouldn't have showed that, it's not truly relevant, just confusing.

They are using it as an example from the `coreboot` project, which is an open source BIOS replacement. They are trying to illustrate how the first instruction executed is at address `0xfffffff0`. The linker script fragment  basically instructs the linker to combine the `.reset` sections from all object files starting at that address. Also the section is padded to 16 bytes, and the symbol `_ROMTOP` is defined. The content of the section comes from the assembly fragment that you omitted:

```
    .section ".reset"
    .code16
.globl  reset_vector
reset_vector:
    .byte  0xe9
    .int   _start - ( . + 2 )
```

As you can see this code is placed into a section named `.reset` and assuming this is the whole content, the linker script will ensure it ends up at the correct address. This is a manually encoded near jump to the actual entry point, named `_start`.